# Nullable int property turns to internal field in public class which doesn't inherits from any class

Tags: c#, properties, nullable

Company class:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

And I get following output in debugger:

[image: Property turns into field]

I need this value binded to XAML, and I suppose this is the reason why value doesn't bind.

Could anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well, I thought it's clearly visible on screenshot, that property CountryId is not property, but field. Somehow

Comment: Note that the fact that you created the `Company` instance via JSON should be completely irrelevant to how the property is shown in the debugger. Do you see the same results if you just create the company with `Company c = new Company { CountryId = 104 };`? If so, you can remove JSON from your question.

Comment: Ok, why is nullable property displayed as internal field?

Comment: Is a non-nullable property any different? Properties have [backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties), even auto-properties. Can you explain how to get it to show in the debugger like that? Even putting a breakpoint on get, I don't see that.

Comment: This sounds like it's just a debugger display issue. Do you have any evidence that anything else is treating this as an internal field? (Have a look at the IL or examine it via reflection and I'm sure you'll see it as a public property.)

Comment: Instead of doing a JSON serialize, can you provide this input as hardcoded initialization and then test? There's nothing in JSON working that will convert a 'public' to 'internal' and 'property' to 'field'

Comment: (I have reproduced the debugger display issue, btw. Hover over the property name when the debugger is broken in any instance member.)

Comment: Edited to reflect, that's JSON has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Daisy What version of Visual Studio? I can't get it to happen on VS 2017 15.6.6, even with a breakpoint stopped on the "get;".

Comment: @john: 15.6.5. Will try updating and see if that fixes it...

Comment: @john VS 2017 Community 15.6.6

Comment: @matt Huh. Weird. I don't think the licensing would make a difference (I'm not using Community).  Either way, it seems likely to be a debugger artifact. I think that Nitin probably has the answer for you, since `int?` is really just `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: @john: I still see it in 15.6.6. I'm going to try a different target framework...

Comment: @john: So do you see a spanner (property) for CountryId in the same way as CompanyId?

Comment: @Daisy [Nope](https://imgur.com/a/XIbrN), not with my framework project. I only see it on `M`, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @john: The second picture there shows the bug - that's showing x.N as if it were an internal field, just like in the question.

Comment: @Daisy Indeed. I just found out what the heart meant :) I will report it as a bug to Microsoft and include a link here momentarily.

Comment: @Daisy [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/232694/public-nullable-property-in-public-class-shows-as.html)

Comment: It's probably worth making it clear that it's not just showing as internal - it's showing as an internal *field* (the box instead of spanner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding to a nullable property, are you binding to the property itself or to the property.Value ?

Bind to the "myCompany.CompanyId.Value" instead of "myCompany.CompanyId".. Nullable fields have extra properties for 'HasValue' and 'Value'and cannot be binded to directly.

Even if you try to bind them to a textbox or use it as general parameter, you will need to do an existence check (via HasValue) and then process the actual underlying value (via Value). So if the CountryId is not initialized, the 'Value' will evaluate to 'null' and your binding needs to be handling that properly. XAML binding handles null easily so you should be good to go :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I suppose that's really just a debugger display issue, and the problem is somewhere else. Unfortunatelly, I can't mark your answer as accepted, I don't want to mislead people

Comment: Actually, it is really this, I really should learn some patience. Thank you.